# How to allow connections only from authorized iphone apps to backend

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8

We are developing an iPhone app that connects to a custom AWS API we build. Besides Oauth, is there any other way we can only allow our paid users to connect to our backend api? Meaning, is there some sort of key that can be assigned to users that buy our apps tied to there apple id's they paid with possible or maybe there MEID?

Comment: Authenticating the device probably doesn't make sense - the user may have multiple devices or switch devices. I suspect you probably need to authenticate the user, in which case you need to manage that between your app and your server. You can't get the Apple ID of the purchaser but you can get the receipt for the app/in-app purchase and correlate that with an account on your server

Comment: Thanks! oAuth it is then.